# Image background position to 50% center the background image but positioned element does not

Tags: css

Image background position to 50% left center the background image but 50% left in absolute positioned element doesn't center the div element why?

Here is the code:

```
 <div style="position:relative;height:100px; background:url(images/demo.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0">
      <div style="min-height:40px; width:140px; background-color:#aaa;position:absolute;top:0;left:50%;">
            heloo this is just a demo
      </div>
  </div>
```

Run this code!

Answer (score 0):

Make the img as block element and float it to left.

You can use display: table to parent div and display: table-cell & vertical-align: middle to the img, this might help in making it align center.

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without code it's hard to understand your problem, but...

Positioning an element absolutely will position it *relative to its parent element*. Make sure the parent element has the correct layout applied to it (width, height, `position: relative`, etc.) and you should see a difference.

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/WmZsk/ the inner div's top-left corner is positioned at 0, 50% of its parent. If you want to center the inner div, the quickest way would be to position it _relatively_ instead: http://jsfiddle.net/WmZsk/1/ You can then put another div over the top of it using z-indexing. It's not terribly efficient, but I can't think of another way (without setting defined widths for the container and the inner div, or using Javascript) to achieve what you want - CSS just isn't cut out for that.